# How to install django-wkhtmltopdf in Pythonanywhere.?

Tags: django, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, pythonanywhere

How to install **django-wkhtmltopdf** in **pythonanywhere**.?

When I try to install with **pip3**. It’s already satisfying
When I run the project its **server error (500)**

**Bash Console**

```
Requirement already satisfied: django-wkhtmltopdf in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (3.2.0)
```

**Server Error Log**

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'wkhtmltopdf': 'wkhtmltopdf'
```

Can wkhtmltopdf be installed on Pythonanywhere?

When I choose an AWS server, do I face a similar problem? Do AWS support wkhtmltopdf.?

How to solve this.? My entire project depends on the PDF reports

Comment: Error says that you have not mentioned where `wkhtmltopdf` file is present or metioned wrong path.

Comment: @VikasGautam : where do I set the path.?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about pythonanywhere, but in windows, I have downloaded wkhtmltox.zip and inside that, I have found `wkhtmltox.exe`.
you also need to install pip package of `wkhtmltox`.

```
import imgkit
config_img = imgkit.config(wkhtmltoimage='../path_of_wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltox.exe')  #in windows
config_img = imgkit.config(wkhtmltoimage='../path_of_wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltox')   #in linux
imgkit.from_string(html, file_path + '.jpg', config=config_img)
```

**for pythonanywhere**

Upload `wkhtmltox` file from upload option present in `file` section in `pythonanywhere`.

check current directory and list files present in that directory and locate your file.

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())                   # current directory path

print(os.listdir(os.getcwd())        # list files present in current directory
```

Comment: how do I configure in pythonanywhere.?
**is that possible in pythonanywhere.?**

Comment: upload `wkhtmltox` file, and then mention file path. In `pythonanywhere` go to files and there you will see upload file option.

Comment: wkhtmltopdf does not work with our virtualisation system at the moment. We're working on that at the moment but, right now, wkhtmltopdf will not work on PythonAnywhere.